# How do you open a ClosedXML Workbook from a stream?

Tags: c#, closedxml

I have an ASP.NET MVC app where a user can upload an xlsx file to be processed.

This creates a `HttpPostedFileBase` object in the upload that has a handy stream method, `HttpPostedFileBase.InputStream`.

I want to process the file using ClosedXML, but I don't know how to construct a `XLWorkbook` object from a stream.  [Other SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655498/reading-from-excel-file-using-closedxml) use a normal file like this:

```
 string fileName = "C:\\Folder1\\Prev.xlsx";
 var workbook = new XLWorkbook(fileName);
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296136/download-file-with-closedxml) explores how to `SaveAs` as stream, but I want to create from a stream.

**So how do you open a `XLWorkbook` from a stream?**

Answer (score 10):

I was cruising around the [ClosedXML Wiki](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki), but did not find anything, so I went and looked at [the source on github](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/blob/develop/ClosedXML/Excel/XLWorkbook.cs).

I found this method:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///   Opens an existing workbook from a stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = "stream">The stream to open.</param>
    public XLWorkbook(Stream stream):this(stream, XLEventTracking.Enabled)
    {

    }
```

Then you should be able to open my HttpPostedFileBase like this:

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook(httpPostedFileBase.InputStream);
```